# Why are x values vertical and y values horizontal in my 2d array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array that I am trying to use to represent sort of a grid in my game. It's 5x3, looking something like:

```
[0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3][0,4]
[1,0][1,1][1,2][1,3][1,4]
[2,0][2,1][2,2][2,3][2,4]
```

The problem is, I want to translate a certain point to a position on my screen but in my 2d array, x seems to be the vertical value and y the horizontal. If I want to add a node at x = 1, y = 2, then I'm effectively going -right- 2 and -down- 1. But when I think of x, I think of a horizontal value (left/right). Am I designing something wrong here? How can I design my 2d array such that x values correspond to left/right movement and y up/down.

I am creating the array as follow:

```
    init(width: Int, height: Int) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


        for y in 0..<height {
            map.append([Tile]())

            for _ in 0..<width {
                map[y].append(Tile(blocked: false))
            }
        }
    }
```

Where tile is just an object that holds it's position and some other irrelevant stuff. Thanks!

Comment: just access your array with `arr[y][x]`

Comment: @vacawama This is a little counterintuitive to me though since I''m so used to x,y

Comment: `x` and `y` aren't graphically/geometrically anything - they're just values in your array. Where's the part where you translate those values to a view? You could've declared or be accessing `row` and `column` backwards from how you built the array, but we don't see that part. if you say `[1][2]` then you are going "down 1 and right 2" because that's how the array access works in the way you've built it here - row, then column. You're thinking of (1,2) as Cartesian (x,y), but that's not what it is. What you're really doing is accessing `[row][column]`.

Comment: Swift doesn't really have multidimensional arrays.  You are just building an array of arrays.  It is natural to build them as a collection of rows, so `arr[row][col]` is that natural order, and `row` is a vertical dimension.

Comment: Change your array to [0,0],[1,0],[2,0]... if it's that important to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of storing your matrix in [row major order, vs column major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

Row major is when iterating the outer array yields rows, iterating the inner array yields elements within the row. Since text output (to a file or terminal) is done row by row, this is preferable for printing purposes. However, it means that when indexing in the form `a[b][c]`, the first index (`b`) is your vertical coordinate (typically called `y`), and the second index (`c`) is your horizontal coordinate (typically called `x`), which doesn't follow the usual "`x` then `y`" convention you're used to. However, you can easily get around this by writing a custom subscript operator, which flips the two indices around:

```
struct Tile {
    let blocked: Bool

    init(blocked: Bool = false) { self.blocked = blocked }
}

extension Tile: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        return self.blocked ? "X" : "-"
    }
}

struct Gameboard {
    var tiles: [[Tile]]

    init(tiles: [[Tile]]) {
        let width = tiles.first?.count
        assert(!tiles.contains(where:) { $0.count != width }, "The tiles must be a square matrix (having all rows of equal length)!")
        self.tiles = tiles
    }

    init(width: Int, height: Int) {
        self.init(tiles: (0..<height).map { row in
            (0..<width).map { column in Tile() }
        })
    }

    subscript(x x: Int, y y: Int) -> Tile {
        return self.tiles[y][x]
    }
}

extension Gameboard: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        let header = (self.tiles.first ?? []).indices.map(String.init).joined(separator: "\t")
        let body = self.tiles.enumerated().map { rowNumber, row in
            let rowText = row.map { $0.debugDescription }.joined(separator: "\t")
            return "\(rowNumber)\t\(rowText)"
        }.joined(separator: "\n")

        return "\t\(header)\n\(body)"
    }
}

let g = Gameboard(width: 5, height: 3)
print(g)
// Example indexing:
let (x, y) = (2, 3)
g[x: x, y; y]
```

Row major order is also preferable because it's the natural consequence of representing a matrix using nested arrays

```
let matrix = [ // Outer array hold rows
   [1, 2, 3] // The inner arrays hold elements within rows
   [4, 5, 6]
   [7, 8, 9]
] // Thus, this matrix is in row-major order.
```

You can use column major order to get around the issue of swapping the indices, but this means that you'll need to [transpose the matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) if you wish to print it line by line or define it using a nested array literal.